# Simple Puzzle Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine

I develop a (really) simple puzzle game that asks you to join a point A to a B (enter/exit) using a ball and mechanisms that you can rotate to give the correct direction to the ball in order to join the exit.

**Here is screenshots of a simple level, showing clearly the purpose of the game:**

[1) New level started, the mechanisms are rotated in a random way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAaYj.png)

[2) Level is completed, all the mechanisms are rotated properly to give the ball the right path to join the exit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwIXV.png)

**Question:**

How can I create an algorithm allowing me to automatically generate levels by taking into account the rotations and leaving only one possibility for the player to complete the level?

I'd also like to add more complexity by adding more mechanisms (to create creating difficulty levels).

---

I don't think it's necessary to talk about tech, but I'm using C# and Unity.

Let me know if you need more information.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this is the right spot for this question. Try http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Great game idea! As to randomly generate puzzel levels, I am somewhat against. These kinds of games are fun because someone has spent time on level design - but if still want to implement randomly generated completable levels and need conceptual advice, I'd refer to the comment above.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I forgot the existence of this stack, I'll try there.

Comment: You have many options for this. Search algorithms, genetic algorithms, planning algorithms, neural networks, etc. I would suggest researching procedural level generation, search algorithms and planning algorithms some more.

Comment: Since you're using Unity3D, you can also ask questions in the [Unity Community](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/ask.html). And you can also try reddit if you're stuck with game development: https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/.

Comment: @Fredrik Thank you! You are probably right, but my laziness tells me that there can be an algorithm for this :) Especially if I want to create +100 levels (or "canvas", since the transition between the levels is "fluid", as if the ball was traveling on an endless "river").

Comment: To generate 100+ solvable levels, I think not really hard; To generate 100+ solvable levels with progressive increasing difficulties which make sense to player, that's really hard for me...

Comment: @PJvG my question wasn't about Unity or programming, but about algorythm creation / level generation. My game is fully playable, I'm just asking if there is some algorythm to generate my levels. Thank you for the response anyway.

Comment: @shole Yes you're right, I don't have any problems to make a lot of levels, the problem is increasing the difficulty in a "natural" way (with parameters, variables…). That's why building an algorythm could be a good start, in order to make some experimentations.

Comment: @Hadrien The Unity Community has [a forum for game design related discussions](https://forum.unity3d.com/forums/game-design.71/), so you can also discuss things not directly related to Unity or progamming there.

Comment: @PJvG Alright, I'll give a try to ask on gamedev.stackexchange and Unity community. Thanks!

Comment: @Hardrien Yes..please let me know if you post a on unity or elsewhere. I am a Unity starter and I am always struggled on similar problems as well... IMO, it sounds more and more like a complex AI stuff to generate suitable levels, because everyone needs to "learn" to feel the difficulty of a particular level  :(

Comment: @shole I posted on Gamedev : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/139346/creating-a-simple-puzzle-resolution-algorythm — and yes, it's kind of difficult to create a perfect level generator… But if I had an algorythm, I could generate levels and then edit them to be more or less difficult.

Comment: @Hadrien Thanks, instantly UV to draw awareness :)  Btw, nice game idea....I feel shameful that I don't even have such simple but fun idea now

Comment: @shole Thanks! It's probably my first minimalist/simple idea since I'm in game dev, and I been there for many years ;) My prototype is already working on mobile devices and the game feel is cool, now I "just" need those +100 levels…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the second image, the game solution is the broken line starting at "ENTER" and ending at "EXIT".

You can create a new level by creating such a line (randomize the number of 'breaks' and their direction). Then you turn each corner into a rotating mechanism thingy. There will only be one legal solution since you will have to rotate the thingies just the right way.

Comment: Good approch! I didn't think about the "broken line" (it's very simple, shame on me!), I'll try that, thank you!

Comment: The trick can be applied in other games as well - generate a random *solution*, then build the problem from it.